# warning: mysqli_query expects parameter

Tags: php, html

[image: Parece que tengo serios problemas con el mysqli jejeje]

Hola, trate de declarar estos parametros pero al parecer me causa error, originalmente eran todos mysql y los cambie a mysqli. ¿Me podrian en donde me equivoco?

LINEAS DE LOS CODIGOS QUE CAUSAN EL ERROR

```
$sql2=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
    if($f2=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){</code>
 $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE Correo='$username'");
    if($f=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){</code>
```

El codigo es un login que identifica correo y contraseña escrita con la BDD

```
require('conexion/conex.php');

$username=$_POST['mail'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];



$sql2=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
if($f2=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
    if($pass==$f2['pasadmin']){
        echo '<script>alert("BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR")</script> ';

        echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";

    }
}




$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM prueba WHERE Correo='$username'");
if($f=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($pass==$f['Contraseña']){
        header("Location: index2.php");
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTA")</script> ';

        echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";
    }
}else{

    echo '<script>alert("ESTE USUARIO NO EXISTE, PORFAVOR REGISTRESE PARA PODER INGRESAR")</script> ';

    echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función mysqli_query requiere que pases como parámetro, un identificador devuelto por mysqli_connect o mysqli_init, no nos pasas el fichero conex.php, pero se deduce que tendrá algo así como:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Entonces la línea que te falla será así:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería así:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
```

En cualquier caso, necesitas revisar documentación de dos cosas:

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134)

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como utilizas `mysqli_fetch_array` en formato funcion, necesita que le pases la conexión como primer parametro:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$sql2 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
```

Tienes más infmación [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que la función espera 2 parámetros de entrada, aunque realmente acepta 3, tu le estás pasando 1 solo parámetro.

> **conexión**    *(REQUERIDO)* : La conexión MySQL sobre la que va a trabajar la función.
>
> **query**    *(REQUERIDO)* : La consulta que se enviará a la base de datos.
>
> **modo**    *(OPCIONAL)* : La constante **MYSQLI_USE_RESULT** o **MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT** dependiendo del compotamiento deseado.

El llamado correcto de la función `mysqli_query()` es:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

En tu caso:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Correo='$username'");
```

Puedes consultar ejemplos simples en [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)