# Por qué no puedo mostrar datos desde MYSQL, en forma de menú desplegable?

Tags: php, mysql

Ocupo lo siguiente:

conectar:

```
?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "cetmetac_mtcm_it";
    $username = "cetmetac_ituser";
    $password = "123QWEzxc";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);?>
```

Mi código que ya no funciona (cambio MYSQL A MYSQLI)

```
<?php
//Creamos la sentencia SQL y la ejecutamos
    $sSQL="Select nombre From it_personal Order By nombre";
    $result=mysqli_query($sSQL);

    echo '<select name="nombresito" class="formSelect">';

    //Mostramos los registros en forma de men� desplegable
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {echo '<option>'.$row["nombre"];}
    mysqli_free_result($result)
    ?></select>
?>
```

Me muestra el select option en blanco... dejó de funcionar cuando cambió mysql a mysqli.

Ayuda o algun codigo que realize lo mismo?.  Gracias.

[image: no muestra nada]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [warning: mysqli\_query expects parameter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138896/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter)

Comment: Prueba  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sSQL); o $conn->query($sSQL);

Comment: Hay algo en los logs de php?

Answer (score 1):

Hola tengo esta propuesta, estoy usando mysql 5.0.12 y  PHP: 7.3.15

```
<!--creamos la conexión -->
<?php 
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "prestashop";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "abc123$";
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
  

?>

    
    
<?php
//Creamos la sentencia SQL y la ejecutamos
    $sSQL="Select * From ps_alias Order By id_alias";
   //aqui van dos atributos, la conexion y la consulta
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sSQL);

    echo '<select name="nombresito" class="formSelect">';

    //Mostramos los registros en forma de men� desplegable
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {echo '<option>'.$row["alias"];}
    mysqli_free_result($result)
    ?></select>
```

Solo te faltaba poner dos atributos, uno cuando se hace la conexión y el otro de la consulta, ya lo he checado y sí funciona, solo sustituye por tus datos. :)